# How do I rename the column number 0 above my index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to rename the '**source**' to something else in the following dataframe

```
source         A to B Diff       B to C Diff
risk_qty       4.909391e+07      0.0000
risk_delta     4.900294e+07      962.5669
risk_mtm       0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_gamma     0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_rho       8.322120e+01      0.0000
```

When I print the column names & indices this is what I get

```
Indices : ['risk_qty', 'risk_delta', 'risk_mtm', 'risk_gamma']

Columns: ['A to B Diff', 'B to C Diff']
```

But my issue is it's neither a column name nor an index, is this even achievable?

**EDIT:**
If it helps I created this dataframe after performing a grpupby sum on 'source'
& then transposing the dataframe.

I tried Sayandip's solution & ended up with following

```
source           A to B Diff     B to C Diff
foo
risk_qty       4.909391e+07      0.0000
risk_delta     4.900294e+07      962.5669
risk_mtm       0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_gamma     0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_rho       8.322120e+01      0.0000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `df.index.name`:

```
>>> df.index.name = 'foo'
>>> df

foo            A to B Diff       B to C Diff
risk_qty       4.909391e+07      0.0000
risk_delta     4.900294e+07      962.5669
risk_mtm       0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_gamma     0.000000e+00      0.0000
risk_rho       8.322120e+01      0.0000
```

Same can be achieved using:

```
df.index.set_names('foo',inplace=True)
```

Ah, got your edit, try:

```
>>> df.columns.name = 'foo'
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work & so I printed df.index.name & it gives me None.

Comment: This is creating a new index with foo instead of renaming 'source'. So I end up having a blank row when I write this df to an html

Comment: Sorry man, I can't reproduce what you are saying. This works fine for me on the data you provided.

Comment: Edited, please check. I thought your index name was `source`, it turns out it was `columns` name.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please have a look?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer as well, please try this one. use `df.columns.name = 'foo'`